# How know the value of property of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object:

```
var x=   {
  "data": {
   "getLand": {
     "id": "xxx",
     "bid": [{
        "result": "ON",
        "buyer": {
           "username": "Dis"
        },
         "offerSet": [{
           "createdStr": "202",
           "value": 1
         }]
       },
       {
         "result": "CANCEL",
         "buyer": {
           "username": "Dis"
         },
         "offerSet": [{
           "createdStr": "202",
           "value": 15
         }]
       }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can i know is `result === "ON"` **&&** `username == "Dis"` ?
I tried with this:

```
  for (var key in x.data.getLand.bid) {
       if((x.data.getLand.bid[key].result === 'ON') && (x.data.getLand.bid[key].buyer.username.toUpperCase() === 'DIS')){
       console.log(x.data.getLand.bid[key]);
       }
  }
```

it gives me some problems .... sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Would you be kind enough to show me another way?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: `toUpperCase() === 'Dis'` would never be true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop of response.json() not work on chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756736/for-loop-of-response-json-not-work-on-chrome)

Comment: There are two issues with your example. 1) In `toUpperCase() === 'Dis'` 'Dis' should be uppercase. and 2) `.bidentrySet[key]` doesn't work.
Which property do you want the value of?

Comment: There are some problems in the console.log, those fields don't exist, I'm guessing you simplified the JSON structure for us and forgot those.

Comment: Is this help for you?
if((x.data.getLand.bid[key].result === 'ON') && (x.data.getLand.bid[key].buyer.username === 'Dis')){
  console.log(x.data.getLand.bid[key]);
 }

Comment: OK first problem is my error... but second problem is very important !

Comment: Using `for in` on arrays is not a good practice

Comment: @Aaron i corrected my code. in the example I reported some errors ... now it's right but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: @charlietfl what i could to use ?

Comment: Numerous ways to loop over an array and easily researched

Comment: @charlietfl please can you share a link or example ? i'm not a good programmer

Comment: Becoming a good programmer requires learning how to research. I promise that finding how to do js array loops is an easy topic

Comment: Why does it not work? The example you give now calls console.log() and outputs the result. What are else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

An example with `for...of`

```js
var x = { data: { getLand: { id: "xxx", bid: [ { result: "ON", buyer: { username: "Dis", }, offerSet: [ { createdStr: "202", value: 1, }, ], }, { result: "CANCEL", buyer: { username: "Dis", }, offerSet: [ { createdStr: "202", value: 15, }, ], }, ], }, }, };

for (const item of x.data.getLand.bid) {
  if (item.result === "ON" && item.buyer.username.toUpperCase() === "DIS") {
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Edit:
If you need the index, you can use `forEach`.

```js
var x = { data: { getLand: { id: "xxx", bid: [ { result: "ON", buyer: { username: "Dis", }, offerSet: [ { createdStr: "202", value: 1, }, ], }, { result: "CANCEL", buyer: { username: "Dis", }, offerSet: [ { createdStr: "202", value: 15, }, ], }, ], }, }, };

x.data.getLand.bid.forEach((item, i) => {
  if (item.result === "ON" && item.buyer.username.toUpperCase() === "DIS") {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

Comment: whit your code how can i know also index of x.data.getLand.bid ?

Comment: @Borja, why do you need the index? If you want to add some prop to  the `item`, you can set like `item.newProp = 1`;

Comment: @Borja, I add forEach , you can get the index `i` from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `filter` and `forEach` loop.

like this:

```js
var x = { data: { getLand: { id: "xxx", bid: [ { result: "ON", buyer: { username: "Dis" }, offerSet: [{ createdStr: "202", value: 1 }] }, { result: "CANCEL", buyer: { username: "Dis" }, offerSet: [{ createdStr: "202", value: 15 }] } ] } } };

x.data.getLand.bid
  .filter(
    ({ result, buyer: { username } }) => result === "ON" || username === "Dis"
  )
  .forEach((el, id) => console.log(el, id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the ES6 array function `forEach` to loop through the array items.

```js
const x = { data: { getLand: { id: "xxx", bid: [ { result: "ON", buyer: { username: "Dis", }, offerSet: [ { createdStr: "202", value: 1, }, ], }, { result: "CANCEL", buyer: { username: "Dis", }, offerSet: [ { createdStr: "202", value: 15, }, ], }, ], }, }, }

const bidList = x.data.getLand.bid
bidList.forEach((bid, index) => {
  if (bid.result === 'ON' && bid.buyer.username.toUpperCase() === 'DIS') console.log(index, bid)
})
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will help you understand it in depth.